# Hostname was not verified ANDROID

Tags: android, web-services, socket.io, ksoap2, ksoap

I am using `ksoap` lib to call the `webservice` . In some cases service run correctly but in a case it gives Host name was not verified 
below is my code for calling `webservice`.

```
 HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, MessageConstant.TIMEOUT_TIME);
            httpTransport.debug = true; // this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // send request
```

here is my log cat for the same

```
java.io.IOException: Hostname 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' was not verified
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:223)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:446)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:152)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
```

Answer (score 1):

This link has several possible causes; none of the responses were marked "accepted":

- [java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619781/java-io-ioexception-hostname-was-not-verified)

You should also look here:

> - http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html
>
> One reason this can happen is due to a server configuration error. The
>   server is configured with a certificate that does not have a subject
>   or subject alternative name fields that match the server you are
>   trying to reach. It is possible to have one certificate be used with
>   many different servers.
>
> For example, looking at the google.com
>   certificate with `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 | openssl
>   x509 -text` you can see that a subject that supports *.google.com but
>   also subject alternative names for *.youtube.com, *.android.com, and
>   others. The error occurs only when the server name you are connecting
>   to isn't listed by the certificate as acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your host as

```
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostVerifier());


 public class HostVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

@Override
public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    Log.i(TAG, "HOST NAME " + hostname);
    if (hostname.contentEquals("XXX.XX.XXX.XXX")) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Approving certificate for host " + hostname);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```