# Android Hostname was not be verified. How to allow all hosts?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get an image from a URL which starts with HTTPS. I keep getting the Hostname was not verified exception.

I took a look at this question [java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619781/java-io-ioexception-hostname-was-not-verified) but didn't understood how to make it work.

Is there any way I can allow all hostnames?

Here's the code thats giving me trouble:

```
public Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) {
    Bitmap x;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return new BitmapDrawable(x);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the TLS certificate is either self-signed or the domain on the certificate doesn't match the server's host name.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26456106/1489860) provides a complete solution:

```
/**
 * Disables the SSL certificate checking for new instances of {@link HttpsURLConnection} This has been created to
 * aid testing on a local box, not for use on production.
 */
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                // not implemented
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                // not implemented
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

        }
    };

    try {

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }

        });
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Simply run that once at any time before making your first HTTPS connection. If you control the server, though, it is strongly preferred to try and obtain a valid certificate instead.

Comment: It doesn't work.I just called this when the user logs in. But I still get the same error when I try to get the image

Comment: Now I called it every time I make an HTPPS connection and my error changed to FileNotFoundException so I guess that solved the problem. Why did you say I should run this just once?