# SSLPeerUnverifiedException OkHttp?

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I'm trying to use OkHttp library to send **post** request to API with some url parameters. Following [this blog post](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp) I have this code so far:

```
    public String okHttpRequest() throws IOException{

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                return true;
            }
        });
        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("myurl").newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("username","username");
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("password","7777");
        String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        //HERE EXCEPTION IS THROWN
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
        return response.body().string();
}
```

The exception is:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname {domain} not verified:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Code for `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1`

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://...")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String message = request.toString() + "\r\n" + e.toString();
                mTextView.setText(message);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            final String message = jsonObject.toString(5);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, message);
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mTextView.setText(message);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

---

Because your project uses ***OkHttp v3.0.0-RC1***, so to fix that Exception, your code should be as the following sample:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://...")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Request request, final IOException e) {
                // do something...
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                // do something...
            }
        });
```

However, instead of `return true;` above, I suggest that you read Google's documentation about [Common Problems with Hostname Verification](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs) for more information.

One more useful link is [OkHttp's HTTPS wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS).

Hope it helps!

P/S: please note that I use async way of OkHttp (at client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()...), you can also use sync way as your code.

Comment: You are just great @BNK ! Request is now sent to a test url for post request. How can add parameters to request url ? /login?username=alvin&password=2186 etc.

Comment: @Alvin for parameters, you can read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142626/how-to-add-query-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-by-okhttp

Comment: is there any particular thing for https @BNK ? Because, it fails when I try to request to my url (https), but all is ok with some test url (http://httpbin.org/ip). I'll accept it ;)

Comment: your `httpbin...` responses `{

    "origin": "118.69.226.223"

}`? Is that your url? About failed, what is the error message?

Comment: I think the problem was with not adding **method()**. Adding that;

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("myPrivateAPIurl")
                .method("POST", ???? )
                .build();

the **method** should take RequestBody instead of question marks @BNK .

Comment: For POST request, pls read https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes, many examples

Comment: What should be the request body ? I think I don't even need that, MediaType things.... I have a url and I have to send a simple post request to that url. No body, no header. What can I do ? @BNK

Comment: POST request with no body? Why don't you use GET?

Comment: I have a url and I have to send a **POST** request with some key-values. (https:://url/login?username=22222&password=3456) That's all what I need. Is the RequestBody those key-value pairs ?? @BNK

Comment: `?username=22222&password=3456` are url parameters and will be displayed in address bar, they are not POST body

Comment: Yes, I also think they are not Body. But How can add parameters to this request?

Comment: Try add it to the url and check. For POST without body, can refer to `RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .build();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://...")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();`

Comment: As I searched, I think that will be the solution =D But I don't have FormEncodingBuilder class.. @BNK =(

Comment: For ver 3, it's replaced with FormBody and FormBody.Builder combo, please read https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: When I use this:


        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("username","22222")
                .add("password","3456")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("myUrl")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

It Fails and the result is:
Request{method=POST, url=myUrl, tag=Request{method=POST, url=myUrl, tag=null}} @BNK

Comment: When you use that, it's POST body, not query paras, try use `url("https:://url/login?username=22222&password=3456"` for example. I am busy now, we'll discuss later :)

Comment: In that case it's sending GET request by default, but I need POST. Ok, I'll wait )) =D @BNK

Comment: @Alvin: I have just updated code for `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you try to connect to a SSL website (https), therefore you need to add a `SSLSocketFactory`, below little code snippet.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

For more details see this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917988/okhttp-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-domain-com-not-verifie) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745342/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-not-verified), it should help you.

If you want to "trust all certificates", see [this](https://gist.github.com/chalup/8706740) example but it`s **not** recommanded and should only be used for **testing** purposes!

Comment: @Alvin see my edit but this is only part of the code, pls see the links for more details of SSL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check SSLSession hostname and your connection host name...

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                if (!urlHostName.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getPeerHost())) {
                    System.out.println("Warning: URL host '" + urlHostName
                            + "' is different to SSLSession host '"
                            + session.getPeerHost() + "'.");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: why setHostnameVerifier can not be resolved ? @nurisezgin

Comment: OkHttpclient api "sethostnameverifier" method prototype in this link https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html