# connect self signed server: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.x.x not verified

Tags: android, ssl, https, self, signed

all
   I will be so grateful if you could help me solve this. I am developing an android app lately. And now I have to connect to server with self signed certificate through Https. I need to make it clear that the certificate is self signed and of course it is not trusted on my android device.
   So I followed the steps on https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.htmlcarefully. Codes are as follows:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getSSL(context);
URL url = new URL(address);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.connect();


protected static SSLSocketFactory getSSL(Context context) {
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().getAssets().open("softRSAroot.cer");
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.d("maggie", "ca= " + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        }finally {
            caInput.close();
        }
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sslSocketFactory;
}
```

Then I got this :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.3.33 not verified:
>    certificate: sha1/gJuuHkIr9IeY7Q42In3rrg0PvKw=
>   DN: CN=192.168.3.33,OU=YJY,O=xxx,L=xxx,ST=xxx,C=CN
>   subjectAltNames: []

The ip address matches the CN, I am keeping working on this hard. 
Thanks for reading and helping me.

Comment: Did you create the certificate correctly?

Comment: You are right! I did not take responsibility for the server, the developer give the certificate to add in and it turned out to be that they did not add the subjectAltNames.     Now,  I have solve this by [javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname not verified:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745342/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-not-verified/30745599#30745599)