# Android Parse implementation cannot verify custom server hostname

Tags: android, parse-platform, hostname

When initializing `Parse` on `Android`, I am able to successfully connect to the Parse server when:
1) I don't specify a server URL, or 
2) I set the server URL to the Parse server.
Because we intend to ultimately migrate our data from Parse to a different host, we would like to connect to a different server URL. 
However, when I try to specify a different server URL (https://api.ourhostname.com/1/) that redirects (serves as a proxy) to the Parse server, the app fails to connect to the server altogether. When implemented from the iOS project, this server URL works fine. However, when implemented on the Android equivalent:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
        .applicationId(APP_ID)
        .clientKey(CLIENT_KEY)
        .server("https://api.ourhostname.com/1/")
        .build()
    );
```

I receive an i/o failure:

```
05-24 21:46:55.319 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:290)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:145)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:139)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-24 21:46:55.324 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Cannot verify hostname: api.ourhostname.com
05-24 21:46:55.329 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:242)
05-24 21:46:55.329 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:486)
05-24 21:46:55.329 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:1226)
05-24 21:46:55.329 7140-7140/com.ourapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1183)
...
```

From a web browser, I am able to visit our custom server URL, which is trusted and valid from the browser, meaning it is not self-signed.

Has anyone else encountered this problem from their Android project, and any suggestions on how to successfully get the Parse SDK to connect to a custom server URL?

UPDATE:
We were able to fix this problem via:
1) Adding [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252178/2321999) on the Android side.
2) Adjusting how our custom server serves its public keys (which was especially crucial in enabling Marshmallow to connect to the server).

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: @gfpacheco I've updated the post with how we fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

We were able to fix this problem via:
1) Adding [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619781/java-io-ioexception-hostname-was-not-verified/15252178#15252178) on the Android side.
2) Adjusting how our custom server serves its public keys (which was especially crucial in enabling Marshmallow to connect to the server).