# Download Manager trust hostname

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

I am getting the following error while trying to download file with `DownloadManager`:

```
[5007] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Hostname my.host not verified:
```

How can I add this hostname as verified for my app, so `DownloadManager` will download my file?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252178/192373. TL;NR: the server does not have a valid certificate on the HTTPS connection.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder if I can trust this unverified link somehow,  like security rules for Retrofit

Comment: There are two ways out: you can 'whitelist' this certificate (e.g. if it is outdated), or fix this on the server side.

Comment: The third way is to add this host via [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)